# Cheapest GPU for Rampage II Gene 2.xx with Core i7 930

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming, pc, cheap, nvidia

Hi I have an old computer my son wants to use for playing Fortnite, Minecraft, etc…

It currently has an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 250 but it can’t play Fortnite because it doesn’t seem to support DirectX 11.

What is the cheapest GPU I can get to play this decently?

[image: System Info]

[image: System Info]

Answer (score 1):

You can get a GTX 1050TI if you're lucky (In Belgium, one shop has it for sale for €169), which is more than enough for Minecraft at full-hd. It also supports DirectX 12, so it can play fortnite, although I don't know how smooth it will run.

And here are some other games I know it will run smoothly: Rocket League (+-120fps ultra) and Dirt Rally (+-60fps ultra/high)